# Opengl not drawing correctly using shader - issue with matrix setup/initialization?

Tags: opengl, matrix, glsl

When I render my app, I'm expecting to see a number of rectangles surrounding the edges of the window. Instead I'm seeing this ..

[image: current result]

All objects will be at `z` == `0.0f`. If I dont render my scene using shaders, all objects show fine. So thinking it must be matrix calculation issue?

Anyone know where I might be going wrong with my matrix setups?

`matrices` is a custom class which contains the 3 matrices ..

```
public class MatrixUtils {

    /* The different matrices */
    private Matrix4f modelMatrix = new Matrix4f();
    private Matrix4f viewMatrix = new Matrix4f();
    private Matrix4f projectionMatrix = new Matrix4f();

    public MatrixUtils(){
        loadIdentity(modelMatrix);
    }

    public void loadIdentity(Matrix4f matrix) {
        matrix.load(new float[][] {
                new float[] { 1, 0, 0, 0 },
                new float[] { 0, 1, 0, 0 },
                new float[] { 0, 0, 1, 0 },
                new float[] { 0, 0, 0, 1 },
        });
    }
}
```

Inside my `GLEventListener`, I setup the matrices with initial values. Called on `reshape`, setup projection, model and view matrices ..

```
/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see javax.media.opengl.GLEventListener#reshape(javax.media.opengl.GLAutoDrawable, int, int, int, int)
 */
public void reshape(GLAutoDrawable gLDrawable, int x, int y, int width, int height) {

    setupOrtho(width, height, 0.1f, 100.0f);
}
```

Model and View matrices are set to identity initially. Projection uses an ortho matrix.

```
private void setupOrtho(float width, float height, float znear, float zfar) {
    matrices.loadIdentity(matrices.getModelMatrix());
    matrices.loadIdentity(matrices.getViewMatrix());
    matrices.setViewMatrix(
        setupViewMatrix(
            new Vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 25.0f), 
            new Vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), 
            new Vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f)));
    matrices.setProjectionMatrix(ortho(0, width, 0, height, znear, zfar));
}
```

Calculate orthographic `Projection` matrix ..

```
public Matrix4f ortho(float left, float right, float top, float bottom, float zfar, float znear) {
    return new Matrix4f(new float[][] {
            new float[] { 2 / (right - left), 0, 0, -((right + left) / (right - left)) },
            new float[] { 0, 2 / (top - bottom), 0, -((top + bottom) / (top - bottom)) },
            new float[] { 0, 0, -2 / (zfar - znear), -((zfar + znear) / (zfar - znear)) },
            new float[] { 0, 0, 0, 1 },
    });
}
```

Calculate `View` matrix ..

```
public Matrix4f setupViewMatrix(Vec3 position, Vec3 target, Vec3 up) {

    Vec3f f = (new Vec3f(target.sub(position))).normalize();
    Vec3f s = (new Vec3f(Vec3.cross(f, up))).normalize();
    Vec3f u = (new Vec3f(Vec3.cross(s, f)));

    return new Matrix4f(
            new float[] {
                    s.x, s.y, s.z, -Vec3.dot(s, position),
                    u.x, u.y, u.z, -Vec3.dot(u, position),
                    -f.x, -f.y, -f.z, Vec3.dot(f, position),
                    0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f});
}
```

Then inside my `display()` loop, I pass all 3 matrices into each object's `draw()` function.

```
public void display(GLAutoDrawable gLDrawable) {

    for (CustomObject obj : customObjects.size()){

        obj.draw(gl2, matrices, getShaderProgram(), obj.getPosition(), 0.0f);
    }

}
```

This is how my custom objects setup `vertexBuffer` ..

```
int COORDS_PER_VERTEX = 3;
int vertexStride = COORDS_PER_VERTEX * 4; // 4 bytes per vertex

ShortBuffer drawListBuffer;
short drawOrder[] = { 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3 }; // order to draw vertices
float squareCoordsTemp[] = {
    -(getWidth() / 2 * getP2M()),  (getHeight() / 2 * getP2M()), 0.0f,   // top left
    -(getWidth() / 2 * getP2M()), -(getHeight() / 2 * getP2M()), 0.0f,   // bottom left
    (getWidth() / 2 * getP2M()), -(getHeight() / 2 * getP2M()), 0.0f,   // bottom right
    (getWidth() / 2 * getP2M()),  (getHeight() / 2 * getP2M()), 0.0f }; // top right
squareCoords = squareCoordsTemp;

ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(squareCoords.length * 4); // # of coordinate values * 4 bytes per float
bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
vertexBuffer = bb.asFloatBuffer();
vertexBuffer.put(squareCoords);
vertexBuffer.position(0);

// initialize byte buffer for the draw list
ByteBuffer dlb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(drawOrder.length * 2); // # of coordinate values * 2 bytes per short
dlb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
drawListBuffer = dlb.asShortBuffer();
drawListBuffer.put(drawOrder);
drawListBuffer.position(0);
```

This is how my `CustomObject` draws ..

```
public void draw(final GL2 gl2, MatrixUtils matrices, int shaderProgram, final Vec3 position, final float bodyAngle){

    gl2.glUseProgram(shaderProgram);

    // enable alpha
    gl2.glEnable(GL.GL_BLEND);
    gl2.glBlendFunc(GL.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    // Set color for drawing
    setmColorHandle(gl2.glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "vColor"));
    gl2.glUniform4fv(getmColorHandle(), 1, getColorArray(), 0);

    // get handle to vertex shader's vPosition member
    mPositionHandle = gl2.glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "vPosition");

    // Enable a handle to the triangle vertices
    gl2.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);

    // Prepare the triangle coordinate data
    gl2.glVertexAttribPointer(
        mPositionHandle, COORDS_PER_VERTEX,
        GL2.GL_FLOAT, false,
        vertexStride, vertexBuffer);

    // get handle to shape's transformation matrix
    mProj = gl2.glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "mProj");
    mView = gl2.glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "mView");
    mModel = gl2.glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "mModel");

    // Apply the projection and view transformation

    // getP2M() == 60.0f .. pixels to meters for box2d
    matrices.loadIdentity(matrices.getModelMatrix());
    matrices.setModelMatrix(matrices.translate(matrices.getModelMatrix(), new Vec3(position.x * getP2M(), position.y * getP2M(), position.z * getP2M())));
    matrices.setModelMatrix(matrices.rotate(matrices.getModelMatrix(), bodyAngle, 0, 0, 1));

    gl2.glUniformMatrix4fv(mProj, 1, true, matrices.getProjectionMatrix().getValues(), 0);
    gl2.glUniformMatrix4fv(mView, 1, true, matrices.getViewMatrix().getValues(), 0);
    gl2.glUniformMatrix4fv(mModel, 1, true, matrices.getModelMatrix().getValues(), 0);

    // Draw the square
    gl2.glDrawElements(
        GL2.GL_TRIANGLES, drawOrder.length,
        GL2.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, drawListBuffer);

    // Disable vertex array
    gl2.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);

    gl2.glDisable(GL.GL_BLEND);
    gl2.glUseProgram(0);
}
```

Vertex shader ..

```
#version 120

attribute vec4 vPosition;

uniform mat4 mProj;
uniform mat4 mView;
uniform mat4 mModel;

void main() {
    gl_Position = mProj * mView * mModel * vPosition;
}
```

fragment shader ..

```
#version 120

uniform vec4 vColor;

void main() {
    gl_FragColor = vColor;
}
```

Definition of `Matrix4f` ..

```
public class Matrix4f {

    public float[] values;

    public Matrix4f() {
        this.values = new float[16];
    }

    /**
     * @param values
     */
    public Matrix4f(float[] values) {
        this.values = values;
    }

    /**
     * @param values
     */
    public Matrix4f(float[][] values) {
        load(values);
    }

    /**
     * @param values
     */
    public void load(float[][] values) {
        this.values = new float[] {
                values[0][0], values[0][2], values[0][3], values[0][4],
                values[1][0], values[1][5], values[1][6], values[1][7],
                values[2][0], values[2][8], values[2][9], values[2][10],
                values[3][0], values[3][11], values[3][12], values[3][13]
        };
    }

    /**
     * Get the values of matrix 
     * 
     * @return values
     */
    public float[] getValues() { 
        return this.values; 
    }
}
```

Matrix functions ..

```
public Matrix4f translate(Matrix4f matrix, Vec3 vector) {

    Matrix4f transform = new Matrix4f(new float[][] {
            new float[] { 1, 0, 0, vector.x },
            new float[] { 0, 1, 0, vector.y },
            new float[] { 0, 0, 1, vector.z },
            new float[] { 0, 0, 0, 1 },
    });

    return multiply(matrix, transform);
}

public Matrix4f rotate(Matrix4f matrix, float angle, int x, int y, int z) {

    Matrix4f transform = new Matrix4f();

    float cos = (float) Math.cos(angle);
    float sin = (float) Math.sin(angle);

    if (z == 1) {
        transform.load(new float[][] {
            new float[] { cos, -sin, 0, 0 },
            new float[] { sin, cos, 0, 0 },
            new float[] { 0, 0, 1, 0 },
            new float[] { 0, 0, 0, 1 },
        });
    }

    //Add onto the matrix and return the result
    return multiply(matrix, transform);
}

public Matrix4f add(Matrix4f matrixA, Matrix4f matrixB) {

    Matrix4f matrix = new Matrix4f();

    for (int a = 0; a < matrix.values.length; a++){
        matrix.values[a] = matrixA.values[a] + matrixB.values[a];
    }

    return matrix;
}

public Matrix4f multiply(Matrix4f matrixA, Matrix4f matrixB) {

    Matrix4f matrix = new Matrix4f(new float[][] {
            new float[] {
                    (matrixA.values[0] * matrixB.values[0]) + (matrixA.values[1] * matrixB.values[4]) + (matrixA.values[2] * matrixB.values[8]) + (matrixA.values[3] * matrixB.values[12]),
                    (matrixA.values[0] * matrixB.values[1]) + (matrixA.values[1] * matrixB.values[5]) + (matrixA.values[2] * matrixB.values[9]) + (matrixA.values[3] * matrixB.values[13]),
                    (matrixA.values[0] * matrixB.values[2]) + (matrixA.values[1] * matrixB.values[6]) + (matrixA.values[2] * matrixB.values[10]) + (matrixA.values[3] * matrixB.values[14]),
                    (matrixA.values[0] * matrixB.values[3]) + (matrixA.values[1] * matrixB.values[7]) + (matrixA.values[2] * matrixB.values[11]) + (matrixA.values[3] * matrixB.values[15])
            },
            new float[] {
                    (matrixA.values[4] * matrixB.values[0]) + (matrixA.values[5] * matrixB.values[4]) + (matrixA.values[6] * matrixB.values[8]) + (matrixA.values[7] * matrixB.values[12]),
                    (matrixA.values[4] * matrixB.values[1]) + (matrixA.values[5] * matrixB.values[5]) + (matrixA.values[6] * matrixB.values[9]) + (matrixA.values[7] * matrixB.values[13]),
                    (matrixA.values[4] * matrixB.values[2]) + (matrixA.values[5] * matrixB.values[6]) + (matrixA.values[6] * matrixB.values[10]) + (matrixA.values[7] * matrixB.values[14]),
                    (matrixA.values[4] * matrixB.values[3]) + (matrixA.values[5] * matrixB.values[7]) + (matrixA.values[6] * matrixB.values[11]) + (matrixA.values[7] * matrixB.values[15])
            },
            new float[] {
                    (matrixA.values[8] * matrixB.values[0]) + (matrixA.values[9] * matrixB.values[4]) + (matrixA.values[10] * matrixB.values[8]) + (matrixA.values[11] * matrixB.values[12]),
                    (matrixA.values[8] * matrixB.values[1]) + (matrixA.values[9] * matrixB.values[5]) + (matrixA.values[10] * matrixB.values[9]) + (matrixA.values[11] * matrixB.values[13]),
                    (matrixA.values[8] * matrixB.values[2]) + (matrixA.values[9] * matrixB.values[6]) + (matrixA.values[10] * matrixB.values[10]) + (matrixA.values[11] * matrixB.values[14]),
                    (matrixA.values[8] * matrixB.values[3]) + (matrixA.values[9] * matrixB.values[7]) + (matrixA.values[10] * matrixB.values[11]) + (matrixA.values[11] * matrixB.values[15])
            },
            new float[] {
                    (matrixA.values[12] * matrixB.values[0]) + (matrixA.values[13] * matrixB.values[4]) + (matrixA.values[14] * matrixB.values[8]) + (matrixA.values[15] * matrixB.values[12]),
                    (matrixA.values[12] * matrixB.values[1]) + (matrixA.values[13] * matrixB.values[5]) + (matrixA.values[14] * matrixB.values[9]) + (matrixA.values[15] * matrixB.values[13]),
                    (matrixA.values[12] * matrixB.values[2]) + (matrixA.values[13] * matrixB.values[6]) + (matrixA.values[14] * matrixB.values[10]) + (matrixA.values[15] * matrixB.values[14]),
                    (matrixA.values[12] * matrixB.values[3]) + (matrixA.values[13] * matrixB.values[7]) + (matrixA.values[14] * matrixB.values[11]) + (matrixA.values[15] * matrixB.values[15])
            }
    });

    return matrix;
}
```

EDIT:

I've set the uniforms to transpose my matrices, but the squares are still not centered. They should form a square around the screen, instead they show like this and also they dont seem to rotate correctly? ..

[image: latest screenshot]

EDIT:

I've changed my rotate and translation functions to multiply the matrices, which fixed the rotated issue. My last issue is that I dont seem to be looking at the center of my scene or my objects are not drawn at the center of my field of view. The squares should form a box around the edge of the screen, with a diamond like shape at center of screen.

Is there something wrong with how I position my camera? ..

[image: latest screenshot]

Comment: You could test it with `gl_Position = vec4(vPosition.xyz * 0.1 + 0.5, 1.0)` to see if it at least draws, then try to narrow down the matrix at fault. Perhaps a row/column major thing, but just guessing.

Comment: Using line you suggested, I just get a green screen. Assuming this is one of the squares just too close. What were you expecting from that line? Considering I can see squares are being drawn already, they're just distorted.

Comment: Without any matrices, you're putting vertices directly in normalized device coordinates (-1 to 1). My scale by 0.1 was so that if you had large geometry it'd fit in the screen. The +0.5 was a mistake sorry as the centre is at 0 and not (0.5, 0.5). Next thing I'd try is just using the projection matrix (which shouldn't distort anything because it's orthographic) and see if you still get squares. Then throw in view and model matrices.

Comment: Using your suggested line multipled by projection matrix, I only see green consuming bottom left hand side of screen. The rest of screen is black.

Comment: Your `setupOrtho` defines the viewing volume as (0,0) to (width,height) so you may want to scale up the positions depending on what getHeight/Width give (compensating for the lack of a model matrix). The other thing is the `z` values of your squares are zero and your viewing depth is `0.1` to `100`. For now I'd change this to `-100` to `100` (without a view matrix you can't move the camera back so the squares are in front).

Comment: Maybe the matrices are just transposed. I cannot see your Matrix4f implementation. But it seems you are constructing the matrices in row major order. OpenGL takes column-major order by default. Try passing true to glUniformMatrix4fv.

Comment: @Maf I've added Matrix4f implementation, hope you can review? @ jozxyqk I create a view matrix using `setupViewMatrix()`.

Comment: What is the value of vertexStride? You can just pass zero for that parameter to glVertexAttribPointer if all the vertices are tightly packed.

Comment: You have to keep the transpose to true. Your matrix is row-major order which is the opposite to what GL expects. The translate() method is definitely not right. To translate something the matrix has to have 1.0 at position 3,3 and then you have to multiply it (either on the left or the right side) with the matrix you want to modify. More here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication

Comment: @samgak `vertexStride` evaluates to `12`. Added code to show how this is calculated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The View Matrix does *not* need to be transposed (it's in column-major order) whereas the Projection matrix is in row-major order and *does* need to be transposed into GL's column-major order.

You can use the appropriate transpose flag as mentioned in the other answers.

The reason you are getting these strange triangles is because the last row of the resulting MVP matrix is not the last row of the identity matrix and thus there is an unintended perspective distortion.

Also, I am not quire sure the view matrix is set up correctly, it should be as follows:

```
 f = normalize(target - position);
 s = normalize(f x u);
 u = s x f;
  _                            _
 |  s.x  s.y  s.z  (-s dot pos) |
 |  u.x  u.y  u.z  (-s dot pos) |
 | -f.x -f.y -f.z   (f dot pos) |
 |   0    0    0         1      |
  _                            -
```

(which needs to be transposed)

Comment: Thanks @wcochran I'm making those changes now to test, does my model matrix need to be transposed after I've applied my translations/rotations etc?

Comment: @bobbyrne01 -- yes -- your translate is in row-major order and thus needs to be transposed!  BTW, the last row should be 0,0,0,1 *not* 0,0,0,0.

Comment: @bobbyrne01 -- the 3rd and 4th row of your rotation matrix should be 0,0,1,0 and 0,0,0,1 respectively (and transposed as well). Wait a minute -- why are you *adding* transformations together -- they should be multiplied!

Comment: i've changed `rotate()` to `multiply` and `translate()` to `add`. If I change `translate()` to `multiply` I get a blank screen.

Comment: @bobbyrne01 Composing transformations is done via multiplication (never addition). The rotation matrix is still incorrect (it will wipe out the z and w values by having the last two rows all 0's).

Comment: Thanks @wcochran I've updated rotation matrix and using multiplication now. Could you take a look at my latest screenshot please? I feel I'm nearly there now, only my field of view doesn't look centered on where my drawing is occuring

Comment: Great. The camera is positioned 25 units down the z-axis, and is looking at the origin with the y axis up. You want to pick the lookat point to be the center of the transformed object. You are using an orthographic projection so picking the location of the camera in conjunction with the view point is important. Try moving the camera back a bit ... maybe 40 units ... you can move it in closer later...

Comment: Changing `setupViewMatrix(new Vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 20.0f), new Vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), new Vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));` to `setupViewMatrix(new Vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 40.0f), new Vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), new Vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));` actually has no affect. I imagined this would have made my objects appear further away?

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear from you question, but it seems that your *Matrix4f* is row-major. Generally, there is two ways how to store matrices: row-major and column-major, however there is one important issue:

> Historically, IRIS GL used the row-vector convention, then OpenGL (which was based on IRIS GL) switched to column vectors in its specification (to make it match up better with standard mathematical practice) but at the same time switched storage layout from row-major to column-major to make sure that existing IRIS GL code didn’t break. That’s a somewhat unfortunate legacy, since C defaults to row-major storage, so you would normally expect a C library to use that too.

Taken from [here](https://fgiesen.wordpress.com/2011/05/04/row-major-vs-column-major-and-gl-es/)

Lets have a look at your view matrix, you have the translation component in it's last row. Assuming that the matrix is row-major, you have build it in transposed way already. When you pass it to the shader with false in *glUniformMatrix4fv*, due to different layout you eventually get a correct matrix. So you do not need to transpose that matrix. However, you should be aware of different order of matrix multiplication, as far as they are transposed. Transposed matrices should be multiplied as follows (it does not apply for your case, because you multiply matrices in vertex shader):

[image]

See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose) for more details.

On the other side, your projection matrix needs to be transposed. More over, there are some issues with signs of elements, check [this](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_projectionmatrix.html). 
Your code should be as follows:

```
public Matrix4f ortho(float left, float right, float top, float bottom, float zfar, float znear) {
    return new Matrix4f(new float[][] {
        new float[] { 2 / (right - left), 0, 0, -(right + left) / (right - left) },
        new float[] { 0, 2 / (top - bottom), 0, -(top + bottom) / (top - bottom) },
        new float[] { 0, 0, -2 / (zfar - znear), -(zfar + znear) / (zfar - znear) },
        new float[] { 0, 0, 0, 1 },
    });
}
```

Try to pass the projection matrix with **true** in *glUniformMatrix4fv*:

```
gl2.glUniformMatrix4fv(mProj, 1, true, matrices.getProjectionMatrix().getValues(), 0);
```

I can only guess how your model matrix is created, so it would be better if you make it just identity for the first time.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I've added implementation for `Matrix4f` if you'd like to review? Also tried setting `projection` uniform to `true` but just made all squares bigger but still distorted.

Answer (score 1):

view matrix is:

```
f = normalize(pos-target);
u = normalize(cross(up,f));
s = normalize(f,u);

|s.x s.y s.z dot(s,-pos)|
|u.x u.y u.z dot(u,-pos)|
|f.x f.y f.z dot(f,-pos)|
|0    0   0       1     |
```

in row-major format = {s.x,s.y,s.z,dot(s,-pos),u.x,u.y,u.z,dot(u,-pos),f.x,f.y,f.z,dot(f,-pos),0,0,0,1}

in column-major format = {s.x,u.x,f.x,0,s.y,u.y,f.y,0,s.z,u.z,f.z,0,dot(s,-pos),dot(u,-pos),dot(f,-pos),1}

projection(ortho) matrix:-

```
|2/(r-l) 0       0        -(r+l)/(r-l)|  
|0       2/(t-b) 0       -(t+b)/(t-b) |
|0       0       -2/(f-n) -(f+n)/(f-n)|
|0       0       0        1           |
```

in row-major = {2/(r-l),0,0,-(r+l)/(r-l),0,2/(t-b),0,-(t+b)/(t-b),0,0,-2/(f-n),-(f+n)/(f-n),0,0,0,1}

in column major = {2/(r-l),0,0,0,0,2/(t-b),0,0,0,0,-2/(f-n),0,-(r+l)/(r-l),-(t+b)/(t-b),-(f+n)/(f-n),1}

use this for column major,

```
gl2.glUniformMatrix4fv(mProj, 1, false, matrices.getProjectionMatrix().getValues(), 0);
    gl2.glUniformMatrix4fv(mView, 1, false, matrices.getViewMatrix().getValues(), 0);
    gl2.glUniformMatrix4fv(mModel, 1, false, matrices.getModelMatrix().getValues(), 0);
```

and this for row-major,

```
gl2.glUniformMatrix4fv(mProj, 1, true, matrices.getProjectionMatrix().getValues(), 0);
    gl2.glUniformMatrix4fv(mView, 1, true, matrices.getViewMatrix().getValues(), 0);
    gl2.glUniformMatrix4fv(mModel, 1, true, matrices.getModelMatrix().getValues(), 0);
```

pick either row or column major matrices and stick to it.

if that does not work then try copying your vertex data to opengl yourself with glGenBuffer()/glBindBuffer()/glBufferData etc...

Comment: changing transpose to `true` for all matrices did not help

Comment: ortho sets width/2,height/2 to be 0,0. if you want 0,0 to map to 0,0 change matrices.setProjectionMatrix(ortho(0, width, 0, height, znear, zfar));  to matrices.setProjectionMatrix(ortho(-width, width, height, -height, znear, zfar));

Answer (score 1):

r

```
eturn new Matrix4f(
            new float[] {
                    s.x, s.y, s.z, -Vec3.dot(s, position),
                    u.x, u.y, u.z, -Vec3.dot(s, position),
                    -f.x, -f.y, -f.z, Vec3.dot(f, position),
                    0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f});
}
```

should be,

```
return new Matrix4f(
            new float[] {
                    s.x, s.y, s.z, -Vec3.dot(s, position),
                    u.x, u.y, u.z, -Vec3.dot(u, position),
                    -f.x, -f.y, -f.z, Vec3.dot(f, position),
                    0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f});
}
```

Comment: still gives the same results as latest screenshot

Answer (score 0):

also check your vertex shader, you have attribute vec4 vPosition, but you are passing in vec3 data.

i think it should be attribute vec3 vPosition and do,

```
gl_Position = mProj * mView * mModel * vec4(vPosition,1);
```

EDIT:
your vertex buffer is:-

```
int COORDS_PER_VERTEX = 3;
int vertexStride = COORDS_PER_VERTEX * 4; // 4 bytes per vertex
```

which are vec3's.

EDIT 2.

can i see your customObjects data that draw uses such as position and bodyangle. could you also print out the proj, view and model matrices before they are passed to your shader program.

Comment: Ok, changing to your suggestion still gives latest screenshot